# Can I create a link to a taxonomy page?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I have a page that has a single category applied to it, for this example, "Self Help Books".

I want to put a place on content type that display a "view all [insert category here]" that links to that category listing page. I was hoping I could do something like `<a href=%taxonomyLink:books--self-help-books%>view all %taxonomy:books%</a>` which would pull in the category for anything using that content type. I'm using the Panels module, so I had planned on placing this in a panel the content type was using.

Is it possible?

I thought about creating a block and placing that in a panel.

Answer (score 0):

There's a default path that links to `taxonomy/term/term_id`. For instance if the `term_id` for the term `Self help books` is 42, the following path will list all self help books.

```
taxonomy/term/42
```

Now, to replace this with the appropriate string, navigate to:

```
Home » Administration » Configuration » Search and metadata » URL aliases
```

and specify that `Self help books` should be an alias for `taxonomy/term/42`.

First, make sure all nodes that you want listed as self help books is tagged with the tag `Self help books`.

Then, to create a link to the nodes tagged with a specific term based upon vocabulary, you need to install and enable the [Token](https://drupal.org/project/token) module and the [Token Filter](https://drupal.org/project/token_filter) module (unless you've already done so).

Next navigate to:

```
Home » Administration » Configuration » Content authoring » Text formats
```

and click `Configure` on the text format (or formats) you plan to use. Under `Enabled filters`. make sure the filter named `Replace tokens` is activated.

You can now see the what tokes that exist by going to:

```
Home » Administration » Help » Token
```

and expand the *Nodes* item.  Let us say that your book category field is named `node:field_book_category`.

Then, if you put an HTML link like this somewhere on a page tagged with `Self help books`:

```
<a href="/[node:field_book_category]">View more [node:field_book_category]</a>
```

you will get a link back to a page listing all nodes tagged with `Self help books`.

This will of course work with any other taxonomy term (e.g. `sport books`, `cooking books`, etc.) as well. However, the node can only be tagged with a *single* term from a particular vocabulary for this method to work.

**Note:** For this to work, the node must actually be tagged with exactly one taxonomy term from the relevant vocabulary.  You can easily check that the node is tagged this way: When you view the content of the node, the taxonomy term or terms it is tagged with is automatically inserted by Drupal with link to a list of all nodes tagged with the term. If this link does not appear, then the node is untagged. If multiple links appear, then there are multiple taxonomy terms. If the node is untagged, there will be no token replacement and the token will appear as plain text. If the node is tagged with multiple terms, then the token will expand into a list of taxonomy categories, and can no longer be inserted in a single link.

PS: As an alternative solution you can override the template for the node (`node.tpl.php`), you can replace the simple link mentioned in the previous paragraph with the string "View more" followed by the link.  This also work if there are more than one tag from the vocabulary on the page.

Comment: If I go to the alias URL I created for the taxonomy term (site.com/categories/selfhepbooks) all the nodes I tagged with that category show with a title, summary, and a read more link. So it is getting tagged.

Answer (score 0):

Create a taxonomy term reference field in the content type where you want to place the link. Select *Books* as the vocabulary so that this field can reference the terms of the *Books* vocabulary. Let the field machine name be *field_book_reference*.

Use the following code.

```php
$node = menu_get_object();
if(is_object($node)) {
  $title = $node->title;
  $book_tid = $node->field_book_reference['und'][0]['tid'];
  echo '<a class="vocab-link" href="/taxonomy/term/"' . $book_tid . '>View all ' . $title . '</a>';
}
```

You may place that code anywhere PHP code is accepted. Better, create a PHP block and place it in a panel.